# POST Request adding table row to SQL DB without data

Tags: javascript, postgresql, fetch-api

I'm sending a rq to my psql that is working because it is updating my db with an extra row on every click (in the right table too). The problem is, it isn't adding in data to that table. I'm trying to post the data from the current cell I'm in, in the for loop, so in this case: newCell. The code is faulty when I try to JSON.stringify the data. I've tried: JSON.stringify(e.value.innerText) and JSON.stringify(e.target.name) but when I check the req.body on the server side, it says it's an empty object (no data).

Here's my client side:

```
openFileButton.onclick = async() => {
    const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();

        for await (const entry of dirHandle.values()) {
            let color = false;
            if (entry.name.slice(entry.name.length-3) === ' BR' || entry.name.slice(entry.name.length-3) === 'DVD') {
                var name = entry.name;
                var newRow = table.insertRow();
                var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
                var newText = document.createTextNode(name.substring(0,name.length-5));
                newCell.className = 'cell';
                var secondCell = newRow.insertCell();
                var secondText = document.createTextNode(name.slice(name.length - 3));
                newCell.onclick = async function(e) {
                    if (!color) { 
                        e.target.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to right, black, greenyellow)';
                        e.target.style.color = 'white';
                        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/movies", {
                            method: "POST",
                            headers: {"Content-type":"application/json"},
                            body: JSON.stringify(e.target)
                        });
                        // console.log(e.target);
                        color = true;
                    } else {
                        e.target.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to right, black, red)';
                        color = false;
                    }
                }
                newCell.appendChild(newText);
                secondCell.appendChild(secondText);
                console.log(entry)
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
}
```

My server side works:

```
app.post('/movies', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const name = req.body;
        console.log(req.body);
        const newMovie = await pool.query("INSERT INTO movies (name) VALUES($1) RETURNING *", [name]);

        res.json(newMovie.rows[0]);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err.message)
    }
})
```

But `console.log(req.body)` returns {}, the post request didn't send any data.

Anyone know the issue?

Comment: *e.value.innerText* is it a valid javascript object? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_stringify.asp

Comment: I meant e.target.innerText, my mistake

Comment: update your code exactly what it reflects from your comments, the idea is that stringify would work only on valid javascript objects, check before sending to post request whether you have a valid object

Comment: I thought of a diff approach. Instead of using json, I changed the content-type of the post request to text/html and in the body specified that I was sending "e.target.innerHTML", still sent nothing

Comment: what do you see if you log *e.target.innerHTML* into console log, do you see any data?

Comment: I see exactly what I'm looking for, the date/string that I want to send into the cell. But when I send to the body of the post request: method: "POST",
                           headers: {"Content-type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8"},
                            body: e.target.innerHTML, and console.log(req.body) on the server size, to see the request that was received, it shows: {}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245996/discussion-between-coder-b-and-ether).